# How to generate QueryDSL mongoDB and lombok in (modern) gradle

Tags: gradle, lombok, querydsl

Getting both QueryDSL and lombok to work together is not simple, especially since gradle  documentation for querydsl is lacking at best.

I want to avoid using autdated plugins that still depend on the `compile` configuration or that are hacking in extra tasks that break other systems (like the intellij idea build).

Going through everything that did not work will take me a while so instead I'm leaving this question & answer here for others (and possibly my future self).

Answer (score 0):

This is (so far) the simplest way to get the compile step to take both queryDSL and lombok correctly into account. The spring-data-mongo starter requirement on annotation processor might be overkill and can possible be done better.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'

ext{
    springBootVersion = "2.7.4"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"))
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo'
}

ext {
    queryDslVersion = "5.0.0"
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    //required to use dependency management to find the right versions. Alternatively specify the version in the dependency directly
    annotationProcessor(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"))
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"

    //querydsl
    implementation("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")
    annotationProcessor("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:general")
    //I'm lazily using the full starter here to automatically include other annotation dependencies like validation. You could specify them separately/specifically
    annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
}

//adding both annotation processors directly on the compiler options make them work together nicely.
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += [
            "-processor", 'lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor'
    ]
}
```